# d3 - calculate position and rotation of element by arc edge

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm starting playing with d3 and I want to achieve this result:

[image: few orange gauges]

I've done this arc thing, but I don't know how to calculate position and rotation of triangle? This is my current code: (http://jsfiddle.net/spbGh/1/)

```
var width = 220,
    height = 120;

var convertValue = function (value) {
    return value * .75 * 2 * Math.PI;
}

var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(45)
    .outerRadius(60)
    .startAngle(0);

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")

var big_background = svg.append("path")
    .datum({ endAngle: convertValue(1)})
    .style("fill", "#f3f4f5")
    .attr("d", arc);

var big_gain = svg.append("path")
    .datum({ endAngle: convertValue(.75) })
    .style("fill", "orange")
    .attr("d", arc);

// HELP with this thing!!!
var triangle = svg.append('path')
    .style("fill", "orange")
    .attr('d', 'M  0 0 l 4 4 l -8 0 z')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `transform` attribute accordingly:

```
 .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + Math.cos(convertValue(.127)-Math.PI/2)*70 + "," +
          Math.sin(convertValue(.127)-Math.PI/2)*70 + ")" +
          "rotate(" + ((convertValue(.127)*180/Math.PI)+180) + ")")
```

It becomes a bit easier if you draw the triangle the other way round. Updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/spbGh/2/).

Comment: `It becomes a bit easier if you draw the triangle the other way round` <- what do you mean? Can you give me another example with this?

Comment: In your code, the tip is pointing up. In my modified jsfiddle, it is pointing down without any rotation.

Comment: Could you help me with transition? How can I achieve motion on arc path? Now my arrow is jumping from place to place: http://jsfiddle.net/spbGh/4/

Comment: Or should I ask another question on SO?

Comment: I've got tween for my arc. But how to connect this tween to this fancy arrow?

Comment: It's the same idea, only instead of calling the arc function, you're passing your intermediate angle to the code that computes the `transform`.

Comment: Thanks for help! If somebody want to know how to do that - this is my current code: http://jsfiddle.net/spbGh/5/